# c++ Overload operator variable (int) in class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have simple class with multiple variable for the same type :

```
class Hello : public HelloPure
{
private :
  int X;
  int Y;
  int Z;
```

I understand how overload work, but i can't find a way to make the following logic work :

```
  mh->X/*Or GetX()*/ += somevalue;
  mh->Y/*Or GetX()*/ += somevalue2;
  mh->Z/*Or GetX()*/ += somevalue3;
```

I couldn't figure out how to reproduce a :

```
 void operator +=(int &val, int val2);
```

That would not lead to a : "too many argument" error.
My main goal is to avoid the following :

```
  mh->SetX(mh->GetX() + somevalue);
  mh->SetY(mh->GetY() + somevalue2);
  mh->SetZ(mh->GetZ() + somevalue3);
```

The reason is that my real environement is a lot more "heavy", and an overload may be more opptimise than the current solution.

Thanks you for future answer.

---

Edit/Update :
A good solution found user253751, but that doesn't work in my specific situation (i'll explain after) is  to return a reference :

```
  int &GetX();
```

and you canse us it :

```
  a->GetX() += 5;
```

But in my situation i can't do that,  i'm actually transfering information between c++ anb c#.

So i have a c++ Pure class pointer that i will use to compute my data, the pointer will be initialize with a CLI (c++/c#) class inheriting from my pure class, and the Cli pointer manage a pointer to my c# class.
When i do a GetX for exemple, it's more like that :

```
  PurePointerClass->GetX()->will call the CLI class GetX() functiun
    and in the GetX() { return m_PointerToManagedC#Object->GetX(); }
```

This make me unable to return directly a reference to my c# variable.

Comment: make them public?

Comment: Unfortunatly i can't, my class inherits from a pure class, and i'm directly using pointer from the pure class.

Comment: Then return a reference? `mh->GetReferenceToX() += somevalue;`

Comment: Add incrementation functions to the interface, so you can write `mh->incrementX(somevalue)`.

Comment: molbdilo that would be too much effort in my situation.

user253751 good idea, i don't know why i didn't tough of that before, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common solution is to use one or more reference wrapper classes. Depending on how different your three cases really are, you may wish to use one wrapper with mutable data, or multiple wrappers:

```cpp
class Hello {
  void* m_PointerToManaged = nullptr;

public:
    class XRef {
        void* m_PointerToManaged;

    public:
        XRef(void* m_PointerToManaged) : m_PointerToManaged(m_PointerToManaged) { }

        void operator+=(int) {
            // your code
        }
    };
    XRef GetX() { return {m_PointerToManaged}; }

    class YRef {
        void* m_PointerToManaged;

    public:
        YRef(void* m_PointerToManaged) : m_PointerToManaged(m_PointerToManaged) { }

        void operator+=(int) {
            // something else
        }
    };
    YRef GetY() { return {m_PointerToManaged}; }

    class ZRef {
        void* m_PointerToManaged;

    public:
        ZRef(void* m_PointerToManaged) : m_PointerToManaged(m_PointerToManaged) { }

        // maybe Zs cannot be added to?
        //void operator+=(int) {
        //}
    };
    ZRef GetZ() { return {m_PointerToManaged}; }
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/8nW6c5

The resulting object still knows about the managed object (alternatively, you can also pass `this` and let it use common functionality of `Hello`), but it is now possible to specify addition operators for an object that is only responsible for one of the three different values.